# Changing a UIImageView based on a URL

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I'm trying to change a UIImageView in Swift from a URL. The code that I have that I attempted to use seems to show that the method `dataWithContentsOfURL` is either deprecated or for some reason the Swift compiler doesn't like what I'm trying to do.

Here's my code.

```
let url2 = NSURL(string: currentAnimation)
    var err: NSError?
    var imageData :NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(url2!, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: err!)
    var currentImage = UIImage (data: imageData)
    self.weatherImage.image = currentImage
```

When I try to do this I get a compile message that the compiler cannot invoke that method with an argument list of those types.

Sorry I'm still new to all of this, so if someone could help that would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change url2! to url2 as the first parameter.

Comment: When I do this it says that there's an extra argument 'options' in method call

Comment: Change NSError to NSErrorPointer. The types in the parameter list must match the method signature.

Comment: Haha well okay, now that I've done that I get the compile message that `url2 "value of optional type is not unwrapped"`, which is why I had the ! in the first place.

Comment: I set the last parameter to nil to get it to work.let url2 = NSURL(string: currentAnimation)
    var err: NSErrorPointer?
    var imageData :NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(url2, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
    var currentImage = UIImage (data: imageData)
    self.weatherImage.image = currentImage

Comment: `let url2 = NSURL(string: currentAnimation) var err: NSErrorPointer? var imageData :NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(url2, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
 var currentImage = UIImage (data: imageData)
self.weatherImage.image = currentImage` is current code yet if I leave `url2` unwrapped I get an error, and if I leave it as is, I get a different error.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Swift is trying to match the parameters you provide with one of its overloaded method signatures. If you provide parameters that don't match exactly to any overload, it will give you error messages until it finds a match. What worked for me is to change the first parameter to url2 and set the last to nil.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a very old version of Xcode? Most Objective-C factory methods have been converted to initializers in Swift. The version that works for me is below -- note that the `NSURL`, `NSData`, and `UIImage` initializers all return optionals, so you need to check or unwrap them to run all this:

```
if let url2 = NSURL(string: currentAnimation) {
    var err: NSError?
    if let imageData = NSData(contentsOfUrl: url2!, 
                                    options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe,
                                      error: &err) {
        var currentImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
        self.weatherImage.image = currentImage
    }
}
```

The `error` parameter of the `NSData` initializer is a `NSErrorPointer`, which is a typealias to `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?>`. That will accept either `nil` or an optional `NSError?` passed as an in/out parameter (i.e., marked with `&`).